# FPU on STM32 Cortex-M4

Tags: assembly, gcc, stm32, fpu

This is going to be very easy for anybody who knows it, but I can't find the answer in any of the docs I have.   I'm trying to find the easiest way to load floating literals to the FPU.

I have done extensive development on ARM7, and lately Cortex-M4 and M7 STM32 CPU types, always using no OS, pure assembly.  Right now I am working on an M4 (STM32L4P5).    I am a newbie with the FPU, though, and trying to come up to speed fast.   I am using the GCC assembler, and have the "-mfpu=vfpv4" switch in my build file.

I can enable the FPU, and then load it with literals like so:

```
ldr           r0,=15
vmov          s0,r0
vcvt.f32.u32  s0,s0
```

and then do math...all that works fine.

I can also load in more difficult floats like so:

```
vldr.f32    s1,zip
vldr.f32    s2,zap

zip:  .float  3.14159
zap:  .float  1.234e8
```

And that works fine as well.  The assembler does the conversion to floating representation, so this is actually more efficient at runtime.

What I'm looking for now is (I'm going to feel stupid) the equivalent
of the common

```
ldr  r0,=15
```

but directly loading the FPU registers.  For example, Zhu's book "Embedded Systems with ARM Cortex-M" says that I should be able to do

```
vldr.f32  s0,=3.14159
```

but the gcc assembler won't take that.  how do I represent a decimal number in an inline literal like that?

Comment: You can load immediates with `vmov.f32`, but it's not 32-bit, so you can only load simpler constants.

Comment: I believe you need to manually encode the floating point number into a hexadecimal integer for this to work.  Floating point constants are only supported with special directives.  I was able to assemble e.g. `vldr.f32 s0, =0x12345678`.

Comment: ARM documetation has an article on the topic - [Assigning immediate constants to single precision floating point registers in 'M' profile](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ka001136/latest), describing the allowed values. But GCC probably doesn't support immediate floating points for `vldr`

Comment: Thanks for the comments, folks.    Fuz:   you don't need to manually encode, fortunately, see my second example - you can let the assembler encode at assembly time at a nearby label...this does work.    Flexz:  I'll check the article, but it sounds like they are talking about what I saw in the Zhu book.  I was hoping that would work with some notation to designate a decimal, sorta like if you didn't know to use 0xHHH for hex.